# Right-click (on text) - clicking on text and right-clicking, add to context menu via REGEDIT, run batch-file using %clipboard%

Tags: windows-7, batch, context-menu, clipboard, right-click

I want to add a functionality to Right-Click.

This will be on the **text-right-click menu**.

*This won't be on the folder-right-click-menu.


Nor


This won't be on the file-right-click-menu.*

[image]

**In the Registry:**

I'd add a KEY, "My Title Copy and Do batch file"

there might be a SUB-KEY named "command"

1. The *functionality* would be, **copy**
2. Use %**clipboard**%
3. **Call batch file with %clipboard%**
4. Done.

The batch file is written and works fine.

**Automation using clipboard and run batch-file is the problem I'm working on. Here is where the right-click on text with use of context menu to run batch file [1-4 above].**

Here's what it would look like:
[image]

Comment: Right click menu, where. Each application implements their own,  you can chose to use the common options, but you dont have to.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as "text context/right click menu" in Windows. Different apps implement different types of context menus, which is easily noticeable, e.g. the `Paste and Go` option visible on your screen is definitely not available for text in Notepad or similar apps. Chrome itself has different context menus for text selections in address bar (omnibox) and on webpages.

You can't also edit that specific menu with Chrome's [contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/) API or anything that's available for extensions.

A workaround would be to use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and set up a keyboard shortcut to do something with the clipboard text if you're in Chrome. Example:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
^+0::
; Copy the selected text
Send ^c
; Run some batch with clipboard
Run, "C:\Path\To\Some.bat", %Clipboard%
```

This assigns it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>.